# How to keep main loop running after running a process by multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My main function runs an infinite while loop that identifies objects by attributing a number to the object. This loop shall not be blocked. Depending on the value of this number a separate process shall be polling  that variable within a while loop that exits only on a certain value of the variable.

I have tried to use multiprocessing for that polling task. But the new process when started apparently stops the main loop so that the object's number is not being changed.
To avoid problems with scope of the variable I set a GPIO-pin to 0 or 1 in the main loop when a certain object is being detected. The GPIO-pin is read within a while-loop within the started process, but it remains unchanged when the object is changing.

How to keep the main while-loop running when the process is running?

```
def input_polling():
    print(rpigpio.input(Pi_kasse)," ..................")
    condition=True
    while condition:
        print(RPi.GPIO(12))
def main(args):
....
    inThread=multiprocessing.Process(target=input_polling,args=[])
....
    while True:
        print("311")
        inThread=multiprocessing.Process(target=input_polling,args=[])
        inThread.start()  
....
    If object==3
        Rpi.GPIO.output(Object,Low)
    else
        Rpi.GPIO.output(Object,HIGH)
    inThread.terminate()
    inThread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use queues to transfer you variable to your sub-process. And in the process use a 'stop'-value as sentinel.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def input_polling(in_queue):
    print(rpigpio.input(Pi_kasse)," ..................")
    # polls the input queue and stops when "STOP" is send
    # will block until element becomes available
    for a in iter(in_queue.get, 'STOP'): 
        print("Doing stuff")

def main(args):
....
    in_queue = mp.Queue()
    inThread=multiprocessing.Process(target=input_polling,args=[in_queue])
    inThread.start()  
    while True:
        print("311")

....
        If object==3
            in_queue.put(your_number)

    # when done put 'STOP' into queue and wait for process to terminate
    in_queue.put('STOP')
    inThread.terminate()
    inThread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Please check it as solution for your problem, so that other users see it.